# How to manage git repository levels?

Tags: github

So there's a project me and my friends are about to start.
Its my first time working in a group more than 2 people, therefore, my knowledge about git is very limited.

How to determine levels in a git repository?
For example: Lets say that I want to have full management about the pull requests to master branch.
However I want my friend to not have the permissions to delete the repository or accept pull request like I do.

Comment: Hi @Daniel. `I want to ask 2 questions` => technically speaking, that's one two many. You should always ask a single question in a post (which is why a 'post' is actually called a 'question' on SO). Please read the help section, especially [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Moreover, both of your questions are too broad and primarily opinion based. Therefore they are considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two empty repositories on GitHub:

- one for you
- one where you add your friend as a collaborator.

Start working locally (`git init; git add .; git commit -m "work"`) and push to the first repository.

Add the second repo as an new remote (`git remote add second https://github.com/me/repo2`) and push to it as well.

Your friend will be able to make PR (pull request) to your first repository, but won't delete or accept anything on said first repository.